# Contains with lastIndexOf?

Tags: java, list, indexing

Is it possible to use a java contains with lastIndexOf?

I am grabbing some information out of a file, and need to grab the last occurrence of it.

the file looks like this

```
17,560.0
17,583.0
17,606.0
```

And I am using something like this.

```
System.out.println(lines.indexOf("17"));
```

However it wont work because it looks for exactly the 17, and wont take any more.
Any way around this?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do, can you please elaborate?

Comment: lastIndexOf returns last index of (exactly) string in parameter. There is nothing to workaround. What you want to get? Maybe you want to grab text after last occurrecne of that string (in this case "17")?

Comment: How do you mean by using lastIndexOf with contains() ? lastIndexOf() returns an integer and contains() take an Object as parameter. And what type is "lines" ?

Comment: how are you arranging the values, is it array of string or comma seperated values?

Comment: I have passed the information in the txt file into a List called lines.
I need to grab the last line containing a 17 (which is the id) in it which then using a split I can just grab the remaining stuff after the  ",".
I suppose their is a better way and I am just doing some unneeded stuff.

Comment: So, this is `List.lastIndexOf`, not `String.lastIndexOf`, right?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo Not entirely, he wants to find the last (String) element in the list that *contains* the String "17". `List.lastIndexOf` will find the last element that is *equal* to the String "17".

Comment: And why do you want to know the index? What are you planning to do with it? Do you relly need the index or the object at it?

Comment: It looks like Curia has a csv file and wants to extract the last number (606.0) associated with 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You will need to loop through the collection to get that kind of `lastIndexOf`.

Something like:

```
int li = -1, i=0;
for (line : lines) {
    if (line.startsWith("17")) {
       li = i;
    }
    i++
}
```

Then you will get in `li` value of last index with a line starting with `17`. If `li` is `-1`, then a value starting with `17` was not found.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your lines are in a `List<String> lines` or something similar, I'd do a reverse iteration over those `lines`, checking whether it starts with the desired value. For example:

```
for (int i = lines.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (lines.get(i).startsWith("17") {
        return lines.get(i);
    }
}
```

Note we start at `lines.size() - 1` and end at `0`, because a `List` index is zero-based.

Comment: Forget my answer. I will also do that @mthmulders is suggesting.